# Angular - ngFor with heavy components

Tags: angular, rendering, ngfor

I ran into a problem: I have an array with chart configs that need to be drawn. Now I am doing as below:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let config of configs; trackBy: getId">
    <chart [config]="config"></chart>
</ng-container>


public getId(index, config): string {
    return config.id;
}
```

These charts are quite heavy in rendering, so when I need to draw more than 6-7 charts, UI starts to freeze a lot. I was thinking of stage-by-stage rendering of charts (do not start drawing the next one until the previous one is drawn). But I don't quite understand the best way to do it.

I tried to use `buffercount(1)`, but didn't get what I wanted. I'm also looking towards the dynamic rendering of the components. Does anyone have any ideas on how best to do this?

Comment: how about trying some virtual scroll to solve this issue? [ngx-virtual-scroll](https://github.com/rintoj/ngx-virtual-scroller)

Comment: @NarenMurali I need to show about 9 charts on one screen, which already causes problems with rendering, so I don't think virtual scrolling will work here

Comment: Is the `chart` component something that you built, or a third party? Can you include some code for it if it is yours?

Comment: @greatstone As mentioned, please share the code, you can set ViewEncapsulation to NONE, maybe it will improve the performance, by reducing change detection!

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu it's just a chart.js component

Comment: The question was if it's just a chart.js component that I have from a npm package, or is it just a chart.js component that I have built myself, and I have source code for it...

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu it's npm package

Comment: Please note that the [first parameter of the trackBy function](https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction) is the index, the second one is the current element of the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by looking at [the `trackBy` function](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor#properties) that you can provide when using the `ngFor` directive. This should reduce the number of times you need to re-render the `chart` component.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let config of configs; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <chart [config]="config"></chart>
</ng-container>
```

The `trackByFn` can return a `string` that is unique, something like an `id` (if your config object has such a thing). If you don't have any id, then you can return a combination of properties that should be unique among the collection elements that you have:

```
trackByFn(index: number, config: any): string {
  return `${config.id}`;
  // or, when you don't have any id, a combination of properties
  // return `${config.type}_${config.value}`;
}
```

The trackBy function also receives the `index` as the first parameter, but you should not use just the `index` to track your items.

Comment: I added a trackby, I updated the question with how it is implemented. The problem is with the first rendering, initialization and rendering of chart data takes a very long time and freezes UI. I have no problem updating them later

Comment: Which npm package are you using for it?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js?activeTab=readme

Comment: This seems to be a vanilla javascript library. You must have a wrapper component for it, like the one that you showed in your question. Can you search through the code for a component that has the `selector: 'chart'` and include the code in the body of your question?